# Ag-Grid: Adding Column Header Icon with css, broke sort functionality

Tags: ag-grid

I tried to add an icon on my column header using css and it broke the sort functionality. Any ideas?

[ag-grid column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZIr0.png)

[css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukUaz.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are making css changes then there is no possibility of breaking sort functionality or any other functionality. You might have changed some alignment in header that might have hidden sort icons